How can I add "blur" the edges of my volume shader?
I'm trying to create this:

This is my result based on some changes I made to this tutorial:

I'm satisfied but I want a less defined border. I also added lens distortion and fog glare in the compositing panel. This is my Shader:


I'm using Principled Volume shader and some Noise Textures to create the "Nebula" effect, but I want to "blur" the edges of the volumes to make it more like the reference image. I tried adding a gradient spherical texture, a color ramp and mix it to the density attribute but it doesn't work with this shader.

Hello and welcome. Please use a title that matches the content of the post. It should read like a question, be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the problem so that anyone searching for similar issues is likely to find this. Remove anything superfluous, avoid using words like "this", "help with", "issue" or "question about", instead describe what "it" is. Remember, your title is the first thing visitors see, answers you get depend heavily on it. See What is the problem of asking “How do I do this?"

Please verbally describe what your issue is, be specific and and use relevant keywords. Avoid referencing images or links as alternative to words, try to stay away from vague references like "this happens", "issue with", "like so", which make the post impossible to find for someone using search. Instead describe what "it" is, be descriptive, succinct and detailed. It may not be immediately obvious to users trying to help what you mean. See What is the problem of asking “How do I do this?"
